Movie filmed with the camera of a character
I vaguely recall a movie where a group of people were hanging out and, and I'm not sure about that, some human sized dinosaurs invaded the city. I remember them going after one of them girlfriend who was blocks away. The scenes that I remember were filmed with a hand camera which one of the characters had with him. At the end of the movie the city is bombed (probably nuked) to remove the treat. They record a goodbye message before the bomb exploded. The movie is more than 10 years old.

I think you're looking for Cloverfield.

@poepje Yup, the duplicate was right :)

Ah, I overlooked that link :p.
Glad you found it!
